# How to merge multiple rows value in one column/row in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have sample data below, I like to merge all the **biggest_win** and **multiplier** in one column for player 1083987121 !

```
select * from player;

player_key, country, biggest_win, multiplier, date
1083987121, USD, 490.2, 163.4, 2020-03-17
1083987121, USD, 256.0, 128.0, 2020-03-17
1083987121, USD, 210.0, 70.0, 2020-03-17
```

What I'm expecting after merge

```
1083987121, USD, 490.2#256.0#256.0 163.4#128.0#70.0, 2020-03-17
1083987121, USD, 490.2#256.0#256.0 163.4#128.0#70.0, 2020-03-17
1083987121, USD, 490.2#256.0#256.0 163.4#128.0#70.0, 2020-03-17
```

Does anyone have a good solution for this? I have tried the XML function seems it doesn't work on BigQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT player_key, country, 
  STRING_AGG(CAST(biggest_win AS STRING), '#') biggest_win, 
  STRING_AGG(CAST(multiplier AS STRING), '#') multiplier, 
  date 
FROM `project.dataset.player`
GROUP BY player_key, country, date
```

with output

```
Row player_key  country biggest_win     multiplier      date     
1   1083987121  USD     490.2#256#210   163.4#128#70    2020-03-17
```

Note: based on your `I'm expecting after merge` example  - I assume you want to have result per combined - player, country and date

> I was wondering if I want to print all the rows

if you want to still output all rows (don't see much value in it - but as you asked) - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT player_key, country, 
  STRING_AGG(CAST(biggest_win AS STRING), '#') OVER(PARTITION BY player_key, country, date) biggest_win, 
  STRING_AGG(CAST(multiplier AS STRING), '#') OVER(PARTITION BY player_key, country, date) multiplier, 
  date 
FROM `project.dataset.player`
```

in this case respective output is

```
Row player_key  country biggest_win     multiplier      date     
1   1083987121  USD     490.2#256#210   163.4#128#70    2020-03-17   
2   1083987121  USD     490.2#256#210   163.4#128#70    2020-03-17   
3   1083987121  USD     490.2#256#210   163.4#128#70    2020-03-17
```

To combine those two new columns into one  - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT player_key, country, 
  CONCAT(
    STRING_AGG(CAST(biggest_win AS STRING), '#') OVER(PARTITION BY player_key, country, DATE), ' ', 
    STRING_AGG(CAST(multiplier AS STRING), '#') OVER(PARTITION BY player_key, country, DATE) 
  ) combined_column, 
  DATE 
FROM `project.dataset.player`
```

with output

```
Row player_key  country combined_column             date     
1   1083987121  USD     490.2#256#210 163.4#128#70  2020-03-17   
2   1083987121  USD     490.2#256#210 163.4#128#70  2020-03-17   
3   1083987121  USD     490.2#256#210 163.4#128#70  2020-03-17
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thank you so much for your answer.  I was wondering if I want to print all the rows how should I do that?  I have re-edited my question a little bit

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer,  can we add one more column to merge at STRING_AGG(CAST(best_win AS STRING), '#', "new column")?

Comment: see updated answer. in case of any more follow up questions - please do post new question instead!

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

```
select player_key, max(country) as country,
       array_agg(biggest_win order by biggest_win desc),
       array_agg(multiplier order by biggest_win desc),
       max(date) as date
from t
group by player_key;
```

Note:  This returns the values in arrays rather than strings -- and arrays are much easier to work with.  However, you could also use `string_agg()`:

```
select player_key, max(country) as country,
       string_agg(biggest_win, '#' order by biggest_win desc),
       string_agg(multiplier, '#' order by biggest_win desc),
       max(date) as date
from t
group by player_key, country;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you so much for your answer it was really helped

Comment: But I like to print all rows and all the rows with the same "490.2#256.0#256.0 163.4#128.0#70.0, 2020-03-17". how should I do that?  I have re-edited my question